# Show that the numerator of $1+\frac12 +\frac13 +\cdots +\frac1{96}$ is divisible by $97$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, divisibility, rational-numbers

> Let $\frac{x}{y}=1+\frac12 +\frac13 +\cdots +\frac1{96}$ where $\text{gcd}(x,y)=1$. Show that $97\;|\;x$.

I try adding these together, but seems very long boring and don't think it is the right way to solving. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you group the fractions in pairs with the first pairing to last, second pairing to next-to-last, etc, you get $$1+\frac 1{96}=\frac {97}{96}, \frac 12+\frac 1{95}=\frac {97}{190}...$$ The sums of these pairs all have a numerator of $97$, and because $97$ is prime the common denominator will not have a factor of 
$97$, so in $\frac xy$, $x$ is a multiple of $97$.

Comment: Very interesting approach...

Comment: Nice approach, and one which lends itself to generalization.

Comment: thanks this turns out be surprise easy

Comment: I found it interesting how both of our solutions ended up with $\frac{p(p-1)}2$, but the way we reordered the sum is completely different.

Answer (score 10):

What we need to do is as follows:
$$
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{96} & = \Big(1+\frac{1}{96}\Big) + \Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{95}\Big) + \ldots + \Big(\frac{1}{48} + \frac{1}{49}\Big) \\
& = \frac{97}{96} + \frac{97}{2*95} + \frac{97}{3*94} + \ldots + \frac{97}{48*49} \\
& = 97 \Big( \frac{1}{96} + \frac{1}{2*95} + \frac{1}{3*94} + \ldots + \frac{1}{48*49}\Big)
\end{split}\end{equation}
$$

Hence, the numerator is a multiple of $97$. To see that the denominator is not a multiple of $97$, note that $97$ is a prime, and the denominator contains natural numbers less than $97$ (in fact, the reduced denominator is a factor of $96$!), hence cannot possibly be a multiple of $97$. Thus, in it's reduced form, the numerator of the expression is a multiple of $97$.

In fact, [Wolstenhomme's  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem) says that the numerator is a multiple of $97^2 = 9409$!

Comment: I like that you mentioned [*Wolstenholme's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, @SangchulLee. It was natural in the context, and is a highly non-trivial fact.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that 97 is prime, and that every nonzero value has a multiplicative inverse mod a prime value, and that modular inverse is a bijection due to it being an involution, then you get:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{96} k^{-1} \equiv \sum_{j = 1}^{96} j \pmod {97}$$

And the result follows from arithmetic sum.

---

More explicitly, letting $p = 97$,

$p \not | y$ because $y | (p - 1)!$ and $p$ is prime and $(x,y)$ are in reduced terms.  Therefore:

$xy^{-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$ iff $x \equiv 0 \pmod p$ implies the numerator of $\frac{x}{y}$ is divisible by $p$.

Since $\frac{x}{y} = \sum_{k=1}^p k^{-1}$, follows that

$$p | x \text{ iff } \sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} k^{-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Let $S_n \equiv n^{-1} \pmod p$ with $n$ ranging from $1$ to $p-1$.  Then $S$ is a bijection, so

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{p-1} S_n \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{p-1} n \pmod {p}$$

And the result follows from

$$p(p-1)/2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Consider $k=14$, which has $j=7$ as modular inverse. In what sense is $\frac{1}{14}\equiv 7\mod{97}$?

Comment: Are you working on $\Bbb{Q}_{97}$?

Comment: @Semiclassical Consider a sequence of values where $S_n = n^{-1} \pmod {97}$ with $n$ ranging from $1$ to $96$.  The sequence of $S$ contains each value from $1$ to $96$ exactly once.  When the sequence is summed over, the order is implicitly being rearranged in order of the values of $S$, not the indices.

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry I'm not familiar with the common notation describing fields and such.  I believe it's not relevant whether I'm explicitly working in a field with 97 values or just applying a remainder function to integers.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting $n^{-1}$ as the modular inverse. That's not a reasonable interpretation of the question, since the questioner explicitly indicates that the sum should be a rational number not an integer.

Comment: @DanielV The idea is right of course, but in order to formalize the proof you need to link the sum of inverses $\pmod p$ with the sum of inverses in $\mathbb{Q}$. That would require at least knowing/proving that the inverses $\pmod p$ are all distinct and that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$, then working out $96! \frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: Well, all you need to know is that $(p-1)! \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}$ has a numerator that is divisible by prime $p$ iff $ab^{-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$.  It follows from how never $b^{-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how that extends to a sum of fractions. It seems to me that to apply that you'd need to put everything over a common denominator.

Comment: @arkeet That modular inverse is a bijection follows from the fact that multiplication is commutative and the inverse always exists, and the values being distinct follows from modular inverse being a bijection.  I deliberately didn't formalize the proof because I'm trying to give the answer of "if you know how to do modular arithmetic, then this is the quick answer".  I think it's beyond the scope of the question to prove basic general results about modular arithmetic.  Wilson's theorem is irrelevant here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DanielV Paraphrasing your argument for one single value $2^{-1} \equiv 49 \pmod{97}$ so the numerator of $\frac{1}{2}$ should be divisible by $49$ which is obviously not true. You *can* prove that your answer does in fact translate to rational numbers, but it doesn't just follow without elaborating.

Comment: I'll try to edit the question to be more explicit...thanks for the comments.

Comment: @DanielV I am not at all disagreeing with that fact. It's just not obvious that a fact about the sum $\sum_n a_n^{-1}$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{97}$ translates to a similar fact in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I added details and welcome comments.

Comment: @Semiclassical - $\dfrac{1}{14} \equiv 7 \pmod{87}$ in the sense that $14 \cdot 7 \equiv 98 \equiv 1 \pmod{97}$. Don't think of $\dfrac{1}{14}$ as $1$ divided by $14$, but as the multiplicative inverse of $14$. It may seem weird, but there is nothing wrong with Daniel's argument.

Comment: @Semiclassical = There was a field of mathematics called **error free computation**, which I can't find any references to, that maps a subset of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbf Z_p$ where $p$ is a large prime number, does the arighmetic in $\mathbb Z_p$ and then maps it back into $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @StevenGregory With that context, yes. But all of this is in the comments, not in the actual answer...

Comment: I don't understand the problem - it is obvious that one can localize at the prime $ 97 $, and use the fact that there is a homomorphism $ \mathbf Z_{97} \to \mathbf Z/97 \mathbf Z $ given by extending the quotient map. The kernel of this homomorphism is precisely the fractions which have a factor of $ 97 $ in their numerator.

Comment: @Starfall Most of the above comments were posted before DanielV's edit. If you read the original revision of his answer, you'll probably agree that it wouldn't have flied at the high school level (where the problem likely originates) without the additional steps and justification added later.

Answer (score 5):

This is along the lines of DanielV's proposed solution.

We know $97$ is prime. Multiplying both sides by $96!$, it's enough to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{96} \frac{96!}{n}$ (which is a sum of *integers*) is divisible by $97$, because $96!$ and $97$ are coprime. Let $a_n = \frac{96!}{n}$ for $n\in\{1,\ldots,96\}$. Then we have $n a_n = 96!$, so $a_n \equiv 96! n^{-1} \pmod {97}$, where $n^{-1}$ is the inverse of $n$ in the integers mod $97$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{96} a_n$ is divisible by $97$ because
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{96} a_n \equiv 96! \sum_{n=1}^{96} n^{-1} \color{red}{=} 96! \sum_{n=1}^{96} n = 96! \frac{96 \cdot 97}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{97}.$$
The red $\color{red}{=}$ holds because the inverse $n \mapsto n^{-1}$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,96\}$.